# adding attributes to array key value pairs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add attributes to existing key-value pairs of an array in javascript. Specifically adding "id" to key, and "quantity" to values.

I have tried to use Object.keys(array) and Object.values(array) to separate and tried to rebuild a new array with Object.entries(array). Have no idea how to add the required attributes into the array. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

The array is as follows:

```
{
    1: "1",
    2: "1",
    3: "1"
}
```

This is the actual result I am looking to achieve:

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        quantity: "1"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        quantity: "1"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        quantity: "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Your object itself is wrong.

Comment: you want array of objects?

Comment: Do you want array of objects or object of objects?

Comment: `{
    {
        id: "1",` is invalid syntax

Comment: sorry, made a typo there. it is supposed to be [] rather than {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want an array of objects, you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in conjunction with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const input = {1: "1", 2: "1", 3: "1"};

let res = Object.entries(input).map(([id, quantity]) => ({id, quantity}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice use of `.entries`, didn't think of that one

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your expected output is incorrect as it is an object with no keys. Instead, you can use an array to store your objects.

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys from your first object, and then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to a new object which contains the `id` (which holds the value of the `key`) and `quantity` (which holds the value of the `value` (`obj[key]`)):

```js
const obj = {1: "1", 2: "1", 3: "1"},

res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({id: key, quantity:obj[key]}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change each key of object using `for..in` loop and push object to a new array.Which have `id:key` and `quantity:obj[key]`

```js
let obj = {
    1: "1",
    2: "1",
    3: "1"
}
let result = []
for(let key in obj){
   result.push({id:key, quantity:obj[key]});
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Was not me, but looking at your code, the down-vote could be, maybe, because mutation of the original object?

Answer (score 1):

A for in loop is your friend when working with objects.
Solution to your question below:

```js
var obj = { 1: "1", 2: "1", 3: "1"}
var newObject = [];
for(var char in obj){
 newObject.push({id: char, quantity: obj[char]})
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObject));
```

Enjoy :)